# NSLog outputs unicode characters as garbage when debugging on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsstring

**EDIT:** NSLog output works well in the simulator, but doesn't work when connected to a real device. And it seems that it is a bug — http://openradar.appspot.com/11148883. Also it happens that it is related to the LLDB, switching Xcode to GDB resolves the problem. Either it's possible to JetBrain's AppCode, which works well with the LLDB.

---

I have a bunch of unicode strings in the application, and if I try to output any of those strings using something like **NSLog(@"%@", aString)** then all the ASCII characters in the string will be printed fine but all the cyrillic letters will be messed up, so instead of

```
newLocation: coordinate:60.019584,30.284954 'Удельная'
```

I'm getting:

```
newLocation: coordinate:60.019584,30.284954 '–ü–æ–∫–ª–æ–Ω–Ω–æ–≥–æ—Ä—Å–∫–∞—è'
```

And that's quite hard to do any debugging with that kind of output. And because that app is targeted for the Russian market only I can't just change locale and use English strings.

So I wonder if there any way to make NSLog work well with unicode characters? And I'm looking only for some kind of **one-liner solution**, I know that there are some ways to write half a page of code and output unicode chars, but I'm looking for something shorter. Ideally I'm looking for some method of NSString that will make it all work. e.g.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [aString someThingThatMakesUnicodeWorkWithXcodeConsole]);
```

Comment: Are you sure that your aString is correctly storing the response? From what you posted I believe the aString didn't store the response correctly, so yes when you do print it with NSLog it will fail. I print greek characters with NSLog all the time. How are you storing the response to the aString ?

Comment: Where do the strings come from? Do read them from a file? When the are inside the code it should work. I tested:   NSString *s = @"Удельная"; NSLog(@"%@", s); and it worked well.

Comment: Those data are coming from a file, but a string literal haven't worked for me either. But it seems that I've found the source — it works well in the simulator, but outputs garbage when connected to the iPhone, so probably something is just wrong with some settings. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know it is relevant to NSLog() and LLDB on some Xcode versions. Have a try with one of these solutions:

- Check log in Xcode Organizer >> Devices >> your device >> Console.
- Use GDB as your debugger instead of LLDB if you are using the latter one. This can be changed from the schema options. Please refer to the steps in the comment by "cocos2d man" below.
- Upgrade to Xcode 4.3.2. Some people say it solved this issue, but I haven't confirmed this myself.

Comment: Thanks, switching to GDB actually fixed it. While switching to 4.3.2 won't help because I'm already using it.

Comment: Anyway its the correct solution , But i can not found this options in organizer 
and after long search in new Xcode i found that we can change the debugger form the schema using the following steps :
1-click on the current schema (it reside beside the stop and play button , and beside the current mode of testing like iphone-simulator ...)
2-choose the option "Edit schema"
3-Open the tap "info"
4-Go to the third drop-down list that named "debugger"
5-change the value from LLDB to GDB

close the window and build and run  again :)

Comment: @cocos2dman Sorry for misunderstanding... The 1, 2, 3 above are three solutions but not 3 steps for one solution. I am changing the numbers with bullets.

Comment: @Halley fine , just i found what you say is correct but con not find the way you mention so i wrote what i wrote :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, obviously you can create a string that will contain and output cyrillic letters. When I was learning Objective-C, I had the same problem in the begining(I'm as well was working with Russian words and stuff like that). So solution is to convert the string to other format like this:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithCString:"Привет, как дела?" encoding:4];
NSLog(@"%@", string);
```

or

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"Этот вариант короче!"];
NSLog(@"%@", string);
```

Hope it helps you!

P.S It means that you need to make create your strings as C-Style Strings, and set their encoding parameter to 4(UTF-8). You can see all list of avaliable parameters in the documentation to NSStringEncoding in NSString.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it happens that in the simulator the russian strings work well by default, and all the proposed solutions, including your one also work. But when I connect Xcode to the real device, the cyrillic letters are outputted as garbage.

Comment: @dsokurenko Unfortunately I can't check this out. What's about localization on your device? I'm really don't know what's the problem, but I will try to figure it out.

Comment: @dsokurenko Everything should be displayed properly, because string in right encoding(UTF-8 is only one that works with Cyrillic properly).

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert it in to UTF8 string.

```
NSString *str = [aString UTF8String]
 NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't fix the output.

Comment: Make sure you need to place @ in nslog

Comment: Actually @"%@" will not work at all because the output of UTFString is a c-string, and with the correct %"%s" format it will output the same garbage as the original string.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it like `NSLog(@"%@", aString);`

**EDIT :**

you can convert it in UTF8 string. This could get you through.

```
NSString *str = [aString UTF8String];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: sure I did it, just mistyped it in the question, thanks anyway.

Comment: I've seen it, but unfortunately it doesn't do the trick, it still outputs the senseless garbage.

Comment: `-UTF8String` gives you a C string; that is, a `char*`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithCString:[[places description] cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding]);
```