# What is the best way to print a log of object with nested NSDictionary or NSArray with decoded unicode symbols?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I look for the best way to print a log of nested objects of NSArray and NSDictionary with decoded unicode symbols.

I know about `description` property, but it prints unicode symbols in \Uxxxx format. Also I know, that it possible to enumerate object and print it's keys separately, but it's not comfortable for big nested objects.

For example:

```
NSArray *array = @[@{@"firstName":@"Марк"},@{@"lastName":@"Цекурберг"}];
NSLog(@"array %@", array);
===
array (
        {
        firstName = "\U041c\U0430\U0440\U043a";
    },
        {
        lastName = "\U0426\U0435\U043a\U0443\U0440\U0431\U0435\U0440\U0433";
    }
)
```

I want to get this:

```
array (
        {
        firstName = "Марк";
    },
        {
        lastName = "Цукерберг";
    }
)
```

I wrote for myself script, that takes `description` string of object and replaces all \Uxxxx (and %xx%xx) to approptiate symbols, but I think it's not the best way.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32986318

Comment: thanks, I tried, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my Objective C script (NSObject extension), that do this:
 https://github.com/iOS-altima/dumpObject

Standard way:

```
NSArray *array = @[@{@"firstName":@"Марк%20%F0%9F%98%9C"},@{@"lastName":@"Цекурберг"}];
NSLog(@"array %@", array);
=== result ===
array (
        {
        firstName = "\U041c\U0430\U0440\U043a%20%F0%9F%98%9C";
    },
        {
        lastName = "\U0426\U0435\U043a\U0443\U0440\U0431\U0435\U0440\U0433";
    }
)
```

dumpObject way:

```
NSArray *array = @[@{@"firstName":@"Марк%20%F0%9F%98%9C"},@{@"lastName":@"Цекурберг"}];
[self dumpObject:array];
=== result ===
array (
        {
        firstName = "Марк ";
    },
        {
        lastName = "Цукерберг";
    }
)
```